# Rails, losing flash after redirect_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I can't figure out why my flash messages disappear after a redirect_to. Started the debugger in my view, and the flash variable is totally empty.

```
flash
=> {}
```

The result is the same with flash.now... It works fine if I edit something and call render.

Controller:

```
  def create
    @user_session = UserSession.new(params[:user_session])
    if @user_session.save
      flash[:notice] = "Logged in"
      redirect_to root_url
    else
      render :action => 'new'
    end
  end
```

Application layout:

```
  - flash.each do |name, msg|
    =content_tag :div, msg, :class => "flash_#{name}"
```

root_url is another controller and action.

Comment: and can you post the code for the root_url controller/action you're redirecting to?

Answer (score 24):

When you use the flash messages feature, there are two ways of displaying messages:

Instantly on the same page load, and accessible in the view from `flash['foo']`:

```
flash.now['foo'] = "Hello world"
```

Or on a redirect to another page, and accessible from `flash['notice']`:

```
redirect_to root_url, notice: "Hello world"
```

The ruby on rails guides website is a really good reference:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#the-flash

Answer (score 7):

If you are using a double redirect (e.g. redirect to root, which then redirects to user), you need to pass the flash on.

```
def first_action
  flash[:notice] = "Logged in"
  redirect_to root_url
end

def second_redirect_action
  redirect_to current_user, flash: flash
end
```

Answer (score 5):

I just ran into this issue too, in Rails 4, and after banging my head against my computer for a while, I noticed this in the Rails logs: `Can't verify CSRF token authenticity`.

Turned out, I was submitting via a form that didn't have a CSRF token in it. Surprisingly, it was still calling my controller method and still doing the redirect, but this was what was throwing everything off.

Adding a CSRF token to my form fixed it.

Answer (score 4):

It was the `render_component` plugin. It breaks rails 2.3.2.

Comment: I solved this issue by commenting out two lines in the render_component code--the line with flash.discard and flash.sweep.  I don't know if this was the right solution, but it's allowing me to move forward at the moment.

Comment: Hi, I also have the same issue here and stuck for half day. I am flashing this way `redirect_to new_user_session_url(subdomain: @account.subdomain),  notice: I18n.t('accounts.create.success_confirmation')` and, I am losing my message on the sessions/new page. However, when I debug on controller I am seeing the flash object with notice key and value. Could you elaborate more on render_component thing you did.

Answer (score 1):

My flash rendering wasn't working for root_url because of my routing. I had the root_url redirected to one another page, like root :to => redirect('[SOME_OTHER_PAGE]'). Instead of this I just use redirect_to to another resource

Answer (score 0):

if you are redirect to another action use flash 
and if you are render to same action use flash.now